# How to set a class style based on the value of a client template of a bound column in an mvc kendo ui grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I guess i'm looking for conditional styling.  If the value of a certain column is true, i'd like to use one css class for the client template in a bound column.  If false, then set another.

What I have (the ternary statement based on the bool value of StartEnabled):

```
columns.Template(e => e.ConfirmationNumber).ClientTemplate("<button id='btnStartStop_#= ConfirmationNumber #'  #= StartEnabled ? class='btnStartClock':'' # onclick='StartStopPSAClock(#= ConfirmationNumber #, \"#= Description #\", \"#= e.SequenceNumber #\")'>Start</button>");
```

throws an error on the visual studio side.
I appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the client templating a lot recently and have found with complex items it is easier to pull it out into a javascript function and then return the rendered results.

here is something that I knocked up which should work for you obviously alter it based on your data types but I have assumed a couple of things here.

```
<script>
    function StyledButton(confirmationnumber, startEnabled, Description, SequenceNumber) {

        var returnString = "<button id='btnStartStop_" + confirmationnumber + "'";

        if (startEnabled === true) {
            returnString = returnString + " class='btnStartClock'";
        }

        returnString = returnString + " onclick='StartStopPSAClock(" + confirmationnumber + ", \"" + Description + "\", " + SequenceNumber + ")'>Start</button>";


        return returnString;

    }

</script>
```

Then to run it just change the client template to:

```
columns.Template(e => e.ConfirmationNumber)
.ClientTemplate("#=StyledButton(data.ConfirmationNumber,data.StartEnabled , data.Description , data.SequenceNumber  )#");
```

This will then render the button as you require.

As I said I find this method easier to manage to javascript rather than having to try and figure out the inlined string of javascript.

Comment: That's cool and I'll mark it for the answer because I tested what you gave me and found it to be cool, but I was curious if you'd tried sending back a temp element.create object with, say return tempobject.outerHTML?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking so if you can just expand on what you are after that would be great and i'll see try to add to my answer if required. Glad the code worked. As I said I had been doing something similar to this on my own project and trying to debug the javascript was next to impossible. Plus it means I can create reusable pieces of JS to use in other grids